# AWS EC2 instance scheduler easily

Tags: amazon-ec2, scheduler, price

I'm using ec2 for development, and it's a waste of money after work. How much time does it take to create a scheduler that automatically starts every morning at 8 am and ends at 7 pm?
I've read the guide provided by AWS, but it's a little difficult.
https://aws.amazon.com/ko/answers/infrastructure-management/ec2-scheduler/

Answer (score 4):

You can easily make your own scheduler using Amazon CloudWatch Events to trigger an AWS Lambda function on a regular schedule.

- Amazon CloudWatch Events has the ability to schedule events, such as triggering a Lambda function
- A Lambda function can do whatever you wish, such as starting/stopping instances based on a tag

See: [Creating an Enterprise Scheduler Using AWS Lambda and Tagging](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/creating-an-enterprise-scheduler-using-aws-lambda-and-tagging/)

Comment: Still they could very well just integrate this into the instance configuration... an actual scheduler with not only this but also request management for spot and dedicated instances. Oh well guess this will have to do for now.

Answer (score 0):

Though its difficult to implement to scratch, you can use [ec2-scheduler.template](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/ec2-scheduler/template.html) to deploy the CloudFormation stack to provision the required platform to schedule.

This approach is more convenient than implementing it from scratch using a scheduled Lambda function and EC2 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

It is also good to make your own guide based, it takes about a week.

Assuming a developer costs around $ 200 per day for a developer, it will take at least $ 1000 for five days of development.
The CloudScheduler service is $ 10 per month, and if you have $ 1000, you can use the service for 100 months, about 4 years.

https://scheduler.gncloud.io/

Service is cheaper than development. Just use the service.

Answer (score 0):

Zero. AWS just release something that does this for free: https://aws.amazon.com/answers/infrastructure-management/instance-scheduler/

This is a Lambda function that runs regularly and looks for tagged resources to power down. The weaknesses are it is pretty low level and you have to make one fixed schedule for your entire team. But is is free.

Disclosure: I work with PowerDown that offers a product that goes quite a bit further and will also handle AutoScale groups and Fargate containers -- and it will create the schedule for you based on user needs. Here is my write up about it: https://www.powerdown.io/blog/posts/2018/announcing-powerdown.html

Comment: It's not free you pay for the resources as always with Amazon, this idea that anything is free in AWS is not very good. Everybody always pays something. This solution according to them costs around $5 per month