# lambda function stop/start ec2 without loss of data

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a EC2 instance with 300 GB of data (EBS volumes attached). I would like to develop lambda function
to start/stop this EC2 during non business hours so save cloud cost. can anyone help me by sharing any sample code/function?

Comment: See also: [amazon ec2 - AWS EC2 instance scheduler easily - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47233856/aws-ec2-instance-scheduler-easily/47233938#47233938)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the scenario could be addressed without lambda:

- [Crone Expressions for CloudWatch Event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html#CronExpressions) with
- targets of [SSM Automation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-automation.html),
- and documents of [AWS-StartEC2Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-aws-startec2instance.html) and [AWS-StopEC2Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-aws-stopec2instance.html).

Note that `CouldWatch Event` has target for stopping an instance. There is no target for starting it. Thus, SSM Automation is proposed.

But if lambda is a requirement, then instead of `SSM Automation`, just use `lambda function` with `CloudWatch Events`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Cloudwatch EventBridge Rule** along with **cron expressions** to define a schedule on which a **Lambda** function runs. Within that Lambda function, you can then turn off your Ec2 instance easily.

```
def turn_off_instance(instance_ids):
  ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
  ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instance_ids)
  logger.info(f'Instance(s) stopped')
```

these two guides do something very similar:

EventBridge:

https://medium.com/geekculture/enable-or-disable-aws-alarms-at-given-intervals-d2f867aa9aa4

Lambda code:
https://medium.com/geekculture/terraform-setup-for-automatically-turning-off-ec2-instances-upon-inactivity-d7f414390800